# Heroku upload file without s3

Tags: php, heroku

I would like to upload some files in my app on Heroku. I read some info to use S3 because it's better, but I really want to upload on Heroku. The uploaded files will no stay longer in my app.

In my local, the upload works but not in my Heroku app.

My controller:

```
$this->file = $_FILES["fileToUpload"];
$this->targetDir = __DIR__.'/';

if (move_uploaded_file($this->file["tmp_name"], $this->targetFile )) {
  // code ...
} else {
  // code ...
}
```

In my local folder, I found the upload file, but when I move my code on Heroku I see nothing on the folder.

I change the folder's permission to 777, it's not a good practice but I want to be sure it's not the problem.

Does anyone have a idea to upload files on Heroku?

Comment: Check the directory your are hitting.

Comment: thx for your answer, on Heroku I see nothing on the folder

Comment: Why do you "really want to upload on Heroku"? Maybe this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). In any case, there's no way to upload files to Heroku's filesystem and have them persist beyond dyno restarts (please see my answer for details).

Answer (score 2):

> I read some info to use S3 because it's better, but I really want to upload on Heroku. The uploaded files will no stay longer in my app.

It's not that S3 "is better". It's that [changes made to Heroku's filesystem aren't persistent](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). They will be lost whenever your dyno restarts, which can happen as the result of something you do (e.g., deploying a new version or changing an environment variable) or as needed (dynos are restarted at least once per day as part of Heroku's regular maintenance process). There's no way around this.

You don't have to use Amazon S3, but you can't store files directly on Heroku's filesystem if you want them to survive indefinitely. (Temporary files may work fine, depending on your needs.)

> I change the folder's permission to 777, it's not a good practice but I want to be sure it's not the problem.

This is irrelevant. You can set any permissions you want and your changes will still be lost on every dyno restart.

Comment: thx for your answer. I would like to upload file on Heroku bescause the uploaded files will be stay temporary. After I would like to a cron to delete all files uploaded to clean.
The user will upload a file, the file will be modify and then the user can download the modified file, so if there are delete when dyno restart it's not a probleme.

Comment: You don't control when your dynos restart (and therefore you don't control when uploaded files get deleted). The very idea of a cron job to clean up doesn't make sense on Heroku. Is that a problem?

Comment: Ok, so I must use an other tools to store my uploaded file. I'm a little bit disappointed, I juste want to try a new tool but in need to use an other tool, I juste want something easy. The cron is not necessary, it's juste to clean and don't have some uploaded files which are not use

Comment: In my application, the uploaded files are some Excel, and I modify then with my code. How can I open and edit then if there are in an others tools, such as Amazon S3 ?

Comment: @user7867717, when you process the files I suspect you need to load them into memory? A quick and dirty option would be to read them into memory directly from the user upload, process them synchronously, then send your HTTP response with the modified data. If you're intending to process them immediately like this the risk of losing files with a regular local upload is low. A more scalable solution would be to save them on S3 and have a background process periodically process those files. Again, you'll need to load them into memory using HTTP or Amazon's S3 SDK.

Comment: thank a lot for your help. I juste do some fix and try few hours later and it's work. I think there is a cache

Comment: l understand more why peaple say to use S3 with your answer, but it's dosen't help me to solve my problem. Hope you will understand my choice